# use method from generic interface

Tags: java, class, generics, interface

I have an Interface like this:

```
public interface Segments <T> {
 List<T> getSegments(); 
}
```

and a class:

```
public class Tree<S, T extends Segmentable<S>>{
}
```

I want to implement and use the getSegments() method from the Interface- but don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to implement the interface in the class as follows:

```java
public class Tree<S, T extends Segmentable<S>> implements Segments<S> {
    
    @Override
    public List<S> getSegments() {
        // Return some List<S> that you want here.
    }
}
```

Or you need to call the `getSegments()` method on an object that implements it already.